# 2D array Swift goes out of bounds when appending arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I want to append elements from one 2D array to the another 2D array, but I get fatal error index out of bound.

the code is as follows:

```
 var array  =  [["a", "b", "c"], ["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]

var array2 = [[String]]()
var x = array.count
var y = array[1].count

for j in 0..<x {
    for i in 0..<y {
        array2[j].append(array[j][i])
    }
}
print(array2)
```

please don't tell me to just copy the array as this is not what I need, I am using this procedure to do something more complex than just copying an array.

Any suggestions as to why it goes out of bounds?

thanks

Comment: You cannot simply say `array2[j]=`. `array2` is _empty_. Element `j` does not exist; _no_ elements exist.

Comment: "please don't tell me to just copy the array as this is not what I need, I am using this procedure to do something more complex than just copying an array" Okay, but then wouldn't it be better to tell us what that is? Because what _you_ are doing is exactly the same as copying array, so it's a pretty silly example to show us.

Comment: it looks like you code and all answers are based off the assumption you want array2 (destination array) to be the same size as your source array.  But you said you want to append, so my guess is the destination array may already have elements in it, in which case doing things like array2[j] will overwrite existing data.  Is it safe to assume destination and source arrays will be same length or destination is of unknown length?

Comment: basically what I want to do is I have an array to start with, then I want to take each element of that array, modify it with a function ( which I have already implemented and works fine), then copy the result of the change I made to that specific element to a second array of the same size of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going out of bounds because `array2[0]` doesn't exist. You need to create an an empty array there before appending to it. Then append that array to the outer array.

```
var array  =  [["a", "b", "c"], ["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
var array2 = [[String]]()

for j in 0..<array.count {
    var stringArray: [String] = []
    for i in 0..<array[j].count {
        stringArray.append(array[j][i])
    }
    array2.append(stringArray)
}
print(array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`array2[j]` doesn't exist as it's just an empty array.

It would be much easier to do this:

```
var array  =  [["a", "b", "c"], ["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]

var array2 = [[String]]()
for item in array {
    array2.append(item)
}
print(array2)
```

> [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]

But that is just copying the array exactly. You should provide a more precise example of what you are trying to achieve.

Another option (Which makes your current code work) is to create a 'row' in the first loop ready for insertion:

```
var array  =  [["a", "b", "c"], ["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]

var array2 = [[String]]()
var x = array.count
var y = array[1].count

for j in 0..<x {
    array2.append([String]())
    for i in 0..<y {
        array2[j].append(array[j][i])
    }
}
print(array2)
```

Which gives the same output:

> [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]